# Tag faces using Picasa 3

Tags: photos, picasa

I totally love using [Google Picasa 3](http://picasa.google.com/) to manage my photos offline, and the ability to share albums with family and friends via [Picasaweb](http://picasaweb.google.com). There is a feature on picasaweb that I'm missing from Picasa 3. Namely **Face Tagging**.

Is there any way of face tagging pictures in Picasa 3? So that I can have the same functionality as Picasaweb?

Comment: The feature is available now, see my post below I updated my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer on Google Help](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93973) indicates that this is a feature only available to Picasa Web Albums.

Comment: I was looking through that myself. Guess I was hoping that there was some update or plugin-like feature that could be implemented

Comment: Maybe in Picasa 4, I'm looking forward to that myself, as I don't like doing it through the webui either.

Comment: I wish there would be face tagging on windows photo gallery. It is much more easier to search for somebody inside many photos

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunatlly no. I wish I could tag local as well, but you have to at present tag what has been uploaded to the web.

> Picasa Web Albums does face recognition
>
> With Picasa 3 out of the way, we gave some of Picasa Web Album's new features a run-through to find that they compliment its desktop brethren's experience pretty well, if not awkwardly at times. Easily the most impressive new feature is "Name Tags," which harnesses facial recognition technology to automatically identify people in photos. This makes it easy to, say, keep a running album automatically updated with photos of Cousin Erin or your parents, but this all has to be done on Picasa Web Albums. Picasa 3 does none of this work on the desktop, and doesn't appear to gain any of the advantages of all this automation and facial recognition tagging.

[Link to full article](http://arstechnica.com/old/content/2008/09/test-drive-picasa-3-gets-off-online-photo-sharing-right.ars)

### **Update**

> The new Picasa 3.5 contains a facial recognition feature similar to the one already present on Picasa Web Albums, but letting it run over your likely vast collection of assorted photos stashed on your hard drive is a lot more convenient. Picasa creates a new sidebar menu list of "People," and asks you to name the folks it finds in its main "Scanning" menu. If you're signed into Web Albums with a Google account stuffed with contacts, that's pretty easy, actually—just start typing a name, then select the contact that pops up as you type.

[via Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5365267/picasa-35-organizes-your-photos-with-facial-recognition)

> Today, I'm happy to announce that we're releasing Picasa 3.5, a new version of our free photo editing software. This version gives you the ability to add name tags to your photos, using the same facial recognition technology that powers name tags on Picasa Web Albums.

[Official Google Blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/09/picasa-35-now-with-name-tags-and-more.html)

Comment: Yea, i came over this article while googling myself. Judging by the date of it, I was hoping something new had come up in the meanwhile. It seems like it isn't so.

Comment: Holy took-a-long-time-to-port-to-the-desktop-version, Batman.

Answer (score 4):

They've just released version 3.5 that integrates face tagging into the desktop client.

It's not bad though it can definitely be improved.  I found the tools to manage the names a little underdeveloped. I'm also not sure if you can add tags manually to an image or if it restricts you to the detected faces.

On the upside, the face detection works well and fast.  It made it through a little over 15k images overnight on my HTPC, now all I have to is add names for all those faces.

[Download link](http://picasa.google.ca/)

Comment: Lower right hand side has a **People** button that lets you add manually. I've noticed a quirk: if you enter a name and hit **Tab** instead of **Enter** it jumps the value around. Overall, a welcome - if overdue - addition though.